# Why isn't my simple regex working?

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of steps, and they are being `echo`'d into the view as `li` items in a `ol`.

So, I need to remove leading numbers (that look like `ol { list-style: decimal }`.

Here is an example array member

> 1. Combine 1 tbs oil...

I tried this regex

```
/^\d+\.\s*/
```

However, it didn't remove the `1.` in the example above

**But**, when I remove the start of line anchor (`^`), it works.

Here is the complete code.

```
foreach($method as &$step) {

    $step = trim(preg_replace('/^\d+\.\s*/', '', $step));
    var_dump($step); // This is what I quoted above
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

### Update

Sorry guys, here is a `var_dump()` of one of the lines..

```
string(43) "4. Remove from heat and cover to keep warm."
```

To me, it doesn't look there is anything before the digit.

Comment: Could it be that the strings have white spaces prepended?

Comment: "But, when I remove the start of line anchor (^), it works."  So what is the problem?  You probably have junk/whitespace at the beginning of the line.

Comment: If it works if you remove `^`, it means the number is not the first character on the line (might be whitespace before it, may be something else, hard to say without an actually defined string).

Comment: @NullUserException @Wrikken @titaniumdecoy @Felix Kling See edit.

Comment: I tried it with your example string and it works for me. It removes the number, the dot and any whitespace separating it from "Remove".

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah, looks like there was some invisible junk at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @alex You'll get buggy code if you use references in the foreach loop. BTW you probably just have some random stuff there, it works for me: http://codepad.org/S0lD6UM2

Comment: @NUE Why's that *You'll get buggy code if you use references in the foreach loop* ?

Comment: @ring0 Here's why: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29992 (live demo: http://ideone.com/dFAtj)

Comment: @Null: scratch what I said, realized derick at php was referring to another comment and not the bug description

Comment: @Null The *bug* is not really a bug, and would not have the behavior as described by the author anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is there any whitespace before the digit?

Try

```
/^\s*\d+\.\s*/
```

Comment: That worked, however, I couldn't see any whitespace there. I probably should of converted `\s` into something so I could see better. Cheers for the answer, I knew it would be something silly.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably extra whitespace around. Also you can get `^` to change its behavior with the `m` modifier:

```
<?php
$s = <<<EOS
  1. Combine 1 tbs oil...
  2. Hello World
  3. Ok then!
EOS;
echo trim(preg_replace('/^\s*\d+\.\s*/m', '', $s));
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew about `m`, but I already has these values in an array. +1